# What does “With the perspective time gives” mean?

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context

Please help, I've tried everything but still can't make out what this clause means. The full sentence is:

> With the perspective time gives, I now realize that the most fitting statement Don Juan  made about dreaming was to call it the “gateway to infinity.”

The official explanation is something like “Looking back, I now realize...”, but I can't see why.

Answer (score 1):

'With the perspective time gives [to me]...' means:

> - I have found this perspective in the time that has passed.
> - The time that has passed has allowed me to see this perspective.

Comment: Thanx,I guess I got it,should`ve thought better. It`s With the perspective THAT time gives.But was is perspective in this case?Is it "True understanding of the relative importance of things"?

Comment: Roughly yes, @L3P. The temporal distance has provided or allowed for a better understanding of the relative importance of Don Juan's statements.

Answer (score 1):

In other words: hindsight is 20/20.

It means that you're often much better at judging a situation *after the fact* rather than *while you're experiencing it*.

See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindsight_bias